# Force website to allow selection of text?

Tags: javascript

I paid for a language learning website, only to find that I can't even select text throughout the site.

They have an "upgrade" account that will let you download the text in the lesson, and I guess the ability to select text is something they're trying to monetize. That's pretty uncool especially for paying customers.

I don't think I'm in moral gray area trying to select the text.

So can anyone help me figure out how? I've tried a bunch of things, but nothing has worked yet.

The website is Fluent U

Update:

They seem to be using basically this and I'm trying to figure out how to reverse it:

```
$('bunch-of-things').
 .attr('unselectable', 'on')
 .css('user-select', 'none')
 .on('selectstart', false);
};
```

Comment: You could inspect or view source and copy it from there.

Comment: Can you add your CSS to the site?

Comment: can you post exact url ?

Comment: The exact url probably requires an account, and it looks like the public pages don't have this restriction... but the code I just added above just needs to be reversed as far as I can tell...

Comment: Have you tried view source and copy from there or disabling javascript

Comment: I did select from sourse, but every character (chinese) is HEAVILY marked up. I even wrote a script to strip the HTML, but it's just time consuming. Also disabling JS won't work because the text is basically subtitles and translations of videos, so it updates every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, figured it out. This seems to do the trick:

```
$('[unselectable=on]').css('user-select', 'inherit').off('selectstart')
```

May be useful for others...

Thanks for the input folks :)

Credit Note: @zerkms helped refine my rather broad selector (*) to '[unselectable=on]'

Comment: You may reduce your selector to `[unselectable=on]`